# Mongoid presence_of embedded document and destroy embedded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid

I have some mongoid document:

```
class Firm
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :offices
  validates_presence_of :offices
end
```

At least one office must be present. It works.
However when 'destroy' method called for latest *office* than *firm* was saved but not valid anymore..

I can use something like this:

```
class Office
    embedded_in :firm
    before_destroy :check_for_latest

    def check_for_latest
       false if firm.offices.count == 1
    end
end
```

but it's not good way

Any ideas? Thanks!